# Evernote- User Provisioning REST APIs

Tags: rest, evernote

I am looking for Evernote REST APIs to integrate evernote to my app. My requirement is that
1. I should be able to authenticate evernote with my app. Are there any OAuth Based authentication supported?
2. I should be able to provision users(CRUD operations) to Evernote. ie Users present on my app should automatically get created on Evernote and should be able to perform basic CRUD operations on users eg. update user attributes, suspend a user, delete a user etc.

I am not looking for Evernote SDKs, looking exclusively for REST APIs. Are these APIs available for Evernote or Evernote Business?

Answer (score 1):

As kentaro says, there is no official Evernote REST API.

There is [a user-created REST API](https://github.com/ttddyy/evernote-rest-webapp) someone wrote as as wrapper around the Java Thrift API.  I've not used it so I can't vouch for it personally.

Also note, however, that while there is OAuth-based authentication (your #1 requirement), your #2 requirement is not possible. There is no capability, via the official SDKs or the REST one mentioned above, to programmatically create an Evernote user account. That can only be done via the Evernote UI.

Answer (score 0):

Evernote is not providing REST API. Please read [docs](https://dev.evernote.com/) and use SDK of the language you use.